# Extracting data from string with specific format using Python

Tags: python, regex, parsing, format

I am novice with Python and currently I am trying to use it to parse some custom output formated string. In fact format contains named lists of float and lists of tuples of float. I wrote a function but it looks excessive. How can it be done in more suitable way for Python?

```
import re

def extract_line(line):
    line = line.lstrip('0123456789@ ')
    measurement_list = list(filter(None, re.split(r'\s*;\s*', line)))
    measurement = {}
    for elem in measurement_list:
        elem_list = list(filter(None, re.split(r'\s*=\s*', elem)))
        name = elem_list[0]
        if name == 'points':
            points = list(filter(None, re.split(r'\s*\(\s*|\s*\)\s*',elem_list[1].strip(' {}'))))
            for point in points:
                p = re.match(r'\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*,\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*', point).groups()
                if 'points' not in measurement.keys():
                    measurement['points'] = []
                measurement['points'].append(tuple(map(float,p)))
        else:
            values = list(filter(None, elem_list[1].strip(' {}').split(' ')))
            for value in values:
                if name not in measurement.keys():
                    measurement[name] = []
                measurement[name].append(float(value))
    return measurement

to_parse = '@10 points = { ( 2.96296 , 0.822213 ) ( 3.7037 , 0.902167 ) } ; L = { 5.20086 } ; P = { 3.14815 3.51852 } ;'

print(extract_line(to_parse))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using re.findall:

```
import re
to_parse = '@10 points = { ( 2.96296 , 0.822213 ) ( 3.7037 , 0.902167 ) } ; L = { 5.20086 } ; P = { 3.14815 3.51852 } ;'

m_list = re.findall(r'(\w+)\s*=\s*{([^}]*)}', to_parse)
measurements = {}
for k,v in m_list:
    if k == 'points':
        elts = re.findall(r'([0-9.]+)\s*,\s*([0-9.]+)', v)
        measurements[k] = [tuple(map(float, elt)) for elt in elts]
    else:
        measurements[k] = [float(x) for x in v.split()]

print(measurements)
```

Feel free to put it in a function and to check if keys don't already exists.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
import re
a=re.findall(r' ([\d\.eE-]*) ',to_parse)
map(float, a)
>> [2.96296, 0.822213, 3.7037, 0.902167, 5.20086, 3.14815]
```

Will give you your list of numbers, is that what you look for?

Comment: No, it isn't. I need something like this: {'points': [(2.96296, 0.822213), (3.7037, 0.902167)], 'L': [5.20086], 'P': [3.14815, 3.51852]}